# Limit with the sinus squared function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

In my assignment I have to determine if the following limit is true or false:

$$\lim_ {x \to 0} \frac {\sin^2(2x)}{\sin(2x^2)}=1$$

I think that it's false. Here is my calculation, and I wanted to know if it's correct:

$$\lim_ {x \to 0} \frac {\sin^2(2x)}{\sin(2x^2)}=$$

$$\lim_ {x \to 0} \frac {(\sin2x)^2}{(2\sin(2x))^2}=$$

$$\lim_ {x \to 0} \frac {(\sin2x)^2}{4(\sin(2x))^2}=$$

$$\lim_ {x \to 0} \frac {1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Is my solution correct?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you get from the first line to the second line?

Comment: It is not correct:  $\sin(2x^2)$ is not at all the same as $(2\sin (2x))^2$.

Comment: Which part isn't true, numerator or denumerator?

Comment: @Alan: Maybe $x\to 0$ instead of $x\to\infty$?

Comment: @mathlove yes, thank you, please see edition

Answer (score 2):

If there's a typo and it should be $\;x\to 0\;$ instead of $\;\infty\;$ :
$$\frac{\sin^22x}{\sin2x^2}=2\left(\frac{\sin2x}{2x}\right)^2\frac{2x^2}{\sin2x^2}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}2\cdot1^2\cdot1=2$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: this limit doesn't exist.

Comment: managed to get that the numerator's limit is zero. I guess the denumrator is zero as well, trying to prove it. thanks.

Comment: Is $$\lim _{x \to \infty} sin (2x^2)$$ $$=$$ $$\lim _{x \to \infty} 2sin (x^2)$$ $$?$$ If it is, it's clear that the denumerator is zero.

Comment: No, both of you limits do not exist...

Comment: @aexl if I write it without the limit? is it true? Just the identities.

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\lim_{\circ\to \color{red}{0}}\frac{\sin \circ}{\circ}=1,$$ one has$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{\sin (2x^2)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{\sin(2x^2)}\cdot\frac{4x^2}{4x^2}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\right)^2\cdot\frac{2x^2}{\sin(2x^2)}\cdot \frac{2}{1}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(2x^2)}{2x^2}}\cdot \frac{2}{1}\\&=1^2\cdot \frac 11\cdot \frac 21\\&=2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use power series. If we take first term in power series of both numerator and denominator .We get 4x^2/2x^2=2. Hence, limit is 2.